# Allocate memory on pointed pointer to char

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, realloc

I am trying to realloc my word list with the word number counter (assume it is set previously). I stick on a segmentation fault at the reallocation line. The word pointer is char-sized.
Where is the actual problem ?

```
// counter
int word_nb = 3;
// buffer allocation
char **word_list;
word_list = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*));
if (word_list == NULL) {
    /*error handling*/
    printf("error word list allocation\\n");
}
*word_list = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
if (*word_list == NULL) {
    /*error handling*/
    printf("error current word into list allocation\\n");
}
char *word = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
if (word == NULL) {
    /*error handling*/
    printf("error word allocation\\n");
}
// realloc to correct size
for(int a = 0; a < word_nb; a++) 
{
    *(word_list + (word_nb-1)) = (char *)realloc(*(word_list + (word_nb-1)), sizeof(word));
}
```

I tried to verify the correct size input on realloc function. I double verified inserted word_list elements. I think there is a lack of memory space somewhere between the word list elements but I can't figure out the pin.

Comment: `sizeof(word)` This is the size of a pointer. That is not a suitable value to resize the buffer to any usefuls size.

Comment: You could make your code way more readable by using array syntax: Instead of `*(word_list + (word_nb-1))` better use `word_list[word_nb-1]`. That would also prevent missing a `*`  as it seems in that line.

Comment: In your code the most important part is missing. What are you doing with your pointers before you try to realloc? With the code shown, `word_nb` must always be `1` as you only have one element allocated for `word_list`.

Comment: My compiled-code is just reallocating allocated word list at runtime. I am not doing other operations on these sweeties. Indeed, it is missing an * that I edited, thanks. I would like to reallocate 3 elements pointed by word_list that should have the word size.

Comment: Where and how to you read some content in your memory? What is `word` supposed to point to with just a single character? What would be the "correct" size without handling some input? You need to enlarge `word_list` before you can hold 3 pointers as you only allocate memory for 1 pointer.

Comment: I would like to write back the correct size to memory that should be 3 char-sized words. I would like to write it through the pointed pointer, assume *(word_list) or word_list[]

Comment: If your words are supposed to have 3 characters, you could start with allocation 4 bytes instead of 1 for `word`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on the assumption that you do proper handling of your pointers between the part where you allocate memory for 1 element each and where you try to reallocate the memory.

This part

```
// realloc to correct size
for(int a = 0; a < word_nb; a++) 
{
    *(word_list + (word_nb-1)) = (char *)realloc(*(word_list + (word_nb-1)), sizeof(word));
}
```

can be written much more readable like this:

```
// realloc to correct size
for(int a = 0; a < word_nb; a++) 
{
    word_list[word_nb-1] = realloc(word_list[word_nb-1], sizeof(word));
}
```

In this line you provide a wrong size. `sizeof(word)` is the size of the pointer, not the length of the content of your string.

Assuming you enlarged the size allocated for `word` properly, you can use `strlen(word)+1` to resize your buffer.

Comment: I recompiled with the actual strlen(word)+1 proposal, it worked. Thank you buddy.